# Mixed content with hls.js

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I am trying to play HLS streams using the [hls.js](https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js) library, the problem is that the site I'm trying to play streams on is https, the url to get the manifest is https so I get that fine but the links to the individual chunks are http.

Hls.js uses XHR to get these chunks, which causes a mixed content error on my site. The stream provider does not serve these chunks over ssl and they don't have such plans in the near future. Is there a clever trickery I can use to get around this without comprmising the security on my site?

I have googled for similar issue with this library and I came across [this](https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/issues/392) issue but it's not resolved. A possible solution would be to open a separate page and load the streams on there but that is last ditch.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was passing an `https` url and requests *still* went out as `http` for some reason. I'm guessing there is some regex or parse error in their code but I was able to fix my mixed content issue with this snippet:

```js
let hls = new Hls({
    xhrSetup: (xhr, url) => {
        xhr.open('GET', url.replace('http://', 'https://'))
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to mix http and https and not receive this warning.